# Tosefes yom tov: What's the maximum amount of time which can be added onto the end of Yom Tov?

Tags: halacha, time, yom-tov, zemanim

The concept of tosefet Yom Tov lets us voluntarily extend the duration of Yom Tov past the time when it would normally end.

What's the maximum amount of time which can be added onto the end of Yom Tov?

Comment: Any reason to think yom tov is different from Shabbat in this regard?